# BXNUI0125E: You will be logged out because you are not a member of an active account - Bluemix Logging error

Tags: authentication, ibm-cloud

BXNUI0125E: You will be logged out because you are not a member of an active account

error i am getting when accessing the dev space in Bluemix

Answer (score 0):

This error message is explained in the Bluemix documentation at the following URL: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/bxnui.html#bxnui0125e

The explanation says: 
"Your Bluemix account might have expired or been cancelled, or you might have been removed from your org. Contact your org manager."